# Add a discount for specific selected payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, discount

Without a using coupon functionality I would like to apply a 15% discount for a specific payment method ID like 'xyz'.

I would like help identifying which hooks to use. The general idea of what I would like to achieve is:

```
if payment_method_hook == 'xyz'{
    cart_subtotal = cart_subtotal - 15%
}
```

The customer does not need to see the discount on this page. I would like the discount to be submitted properly, only for the specific payment method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this custom function hooked in `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` action hook, that will make a discount of 15% for a defined payment method.

You should need to set in this function your real payment method ID *(like 'bacs', 'cod', 'cheque' or 'paypal')*.

The 2nd function will refresh checkout data each time that a payment method is selected.

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','shipping_method_discount', 20, 1 );
function shipping_method_discount( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // HERE Define your targeted shipping method ID
    $payment_method = 'bacs';

    // The percent to apply
    $percent = 15; // 15%

    $cart_total = $cart_object->subtotal_ex_tax;
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    if( $payment_method == $chosen_payment_method ){
        $label_text = __( "Shipping discount 15%" );
        // Calculation
        $discount = number_format(($cart_total / 100) * $percent, 2);
        // Add the discount
        $cart_object->add_fee( $label_text, -$discount, false );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'refresh_payment_methods' );
function refresh_payment_methods(){
    // jQuery code
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and works.

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was seeking. Thank you Loic!

Comment: But How can we limit the amount we are providing, I have used this condition but still I get more than 200 discount sometimes,

```
if($discount > 200){
            $cart_object->add_fee( $label_text, -200, false );
  }else{
   $cart_object->add_fee( $label_text, -$discount, false );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help others.. I needed to check the payment method for 2 methods AND check if the user was a specific role..

```
if (($chosen_payment_method == 'stripe' || $chosen_payment_method == 'paypal') && current_user_can('dealer')) {
```